# Target Specific File - NO-CACHE PHP

Tags: php, caching, twig

I'm using the following code to prevent a page from caching a twig `random()` command.

```
<?php
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

I am only using the `random()` command on a single page, but the file that controls caching is global, is there away to target a specific file ie. `default.html` ? Instead of preventing caching for the entire site?

Answer (score 1):

You should disable the caching on the Response object for that specific page:

```
$response->setPrivate()
```

Also see the API documentation: http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html#method_setPrivate

Comment: This is a little bit advanced for me. I am using staceyapp 3, it uses Twig. How would I go about locating the Response Object for that specific page?

Comment: You marked your question with the `symfony2` tag. Don't know the details about `staceyapp`.